# Program native back button in SAPUI5

Tags: cordova, sapui5

I'm writing an SAPUI5 app. I've implemented the view's `navButtonPress` event, but the native (browser, android) back button wouldn't trigger the function in my controller. Any suggestions?

P/s: I'm sorry if my explanation is unclear. Feel free to ask for further detail or giving advices.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to expect that you function in controller will be triggered on the native buttons press. Your function will be triggered once user presses on the in-app "back button" (for example in "Page" control).

When user clicks on the "native" buttons the standard [history traveling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History_API/%20%22History) will take place, you cannot control that (at least browser's back button).

Comment: yeah that's my problem. I can't control the native button. I've gone for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set this in your view, e.g.

```
...
<Page
    navButtonPress="onNavButton"
    showNavButton="true"
...
```

and this in the respective controller, e.g.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History"
    ...
    ], function (History, ...) {
    ...
    onNavButton: function(oEvent) {
        var oHistory, sPreviousHash;
        oHistory = History.getInstance();
        sPreviousHash = oHistory.getPreviousHash();
        if (sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
            window.history.go(-1);
        } else {
            this.getRouter().navTo("yourStartPage", {}, true);
        }
    },
...
```

Comment: I did sir. but it not's do anygood, it's not about theUI5 nav back event, that function works as well as expected. I'm having troubles with the native (browser, android) back button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a navigation based on the hash-part of the URL, in order to have the same behaviour of the browsers back button and the applications back button.
Check the "[Navigation and Routing](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d.html)" chapter in the SAP UI5 tutorials.